# Multiple thread accessing same DB tables from two different DB connections

Tags: multithreading, sql-server-2005, visual-c++

I have some threads running on my program(each thread has its own connection to DB), which want to access the same tables will it cause any problems?

to be simple

I have:

- 2 threads T1 and T2
- 2 DB connections C1 and C2
- 1 table DBTable1
- T1 is always uses C1 and T2 always uses C2
- T1 is keep on inserting, deleting, updating table DBTable1
- T2 is reading the table DBTable1

Will there be any issues?

i am using MS SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Databases are specifically designed to handle concurrent users in these scenarios using [transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction#In_SQL).

Comment: You are.  As my link explains, SQL databases are transaction-oriented.  The default is auto-commit after each statement.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have no problems. Database engines are designed for concurrency

If T2 calls while T1 is writing, it will wait until T1 finishes. This is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as the database transactions follows [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) which makes sure of Concurrency through its Isolation property between different thread Operations.